# put multiline variable value to a curl message in telegram

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, curl

I want to send `$log` as a message in telegram using curl. It works when the variable value is one line only but I'm getting the error `curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL` when its not (when the variable value is more than one line).

log.log:

```
>tail -3 /home/name/log.log
sftp> ls -l /home/somefile.txt
/home/somefile.txt
sftp>
```

command:

```
log=`tail -3 /home/name/log.log`
curl 'https://api.telegram.org/bot$BOT/sendMessage?chat_id=$channelID&text=Found: $log'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a POST request and double quotes to expand your variables:

```
log=$(tail -3 /home/name/log.log)
curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot$BOT/sendMessage"\
    -d chat_id="$channelID" -d text="Found: $log"
```

`-X POST` is optional here, using the data option `-d` is sufficient for a POST request (content-type
application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

Comment: Thanks! How do I add new line before $log?

Comment: You can use `-d text=$'Found:\n'"$log"`